# Custom popup like infoWindow for button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to find a way to create a custom popup like **infowindow** for buttons but I am not able to find out any tutorial or any other solution for this. Can anyone guide me to create a popup like **infowindow** for buttons [button with custom popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xAsc.png)

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of libraries available for this type of feature -

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521455/Quick-action-pattern-in-Android-and-simple-impleme
2. http://shardulprabhu.blogspot.ro/2012/08/blog-post_29.html
3. https://github.com/michaelye/EasyDialog

You can go through these links and use any of those you like.